# Is there a function to retrieve the underlying InputStream/OutputStream from com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange?

Tags: java, com.sun.net.httpserver

I have a large custom-built web server in Java, which wraps the `com.sun.net.httpserver` API and adds a number of utility functions to build a full-blown website.  I also added the ability for the web server to handle WebSocket requests.  In order to do this, the web server needs to get access to the underlying `InputStream` and `OutputStream` of the `HttpExchange` so it can do the necessary bit-fiddling and send the data back without HTTP headers.  I have written some code to do this and verified that it works on my JVM, but the code to do so is rather... questionable, so I am curious if there is a better way to get at the underlying streams.  The code I have now to get the underlying streams:

```java
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;

import sun.misc.Unsafe;
import web.WebServer.IOStream;

/**
 * "Undefined behavior"? I think you mean, "designed effects"
 * <p>
 * Before reading this class, you should keep in mind that that this is called
 * <code>HttpExchange<b>Hack</b></code> for a reason
 * @author Derek McCants
 */
public class HttpExchangeHack
{
    /**
     * Yeah, one line in and things are already going sideways
     */
    private static Unsafe unsafe;
    static
    {
        try {
            Field f = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            unsafe = (Unsafe)f.get(null);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };
    
    /**
     * Retrieves the specified field from the specified parent object,
     * bypassing all Java access controls and security checks.
     * <p>
     * Or crashes the underlying JVM, depending on what mood we're in.
     * <p>
     * This works by systematically corrupting the memory around the desired
     * object until we overwrite the override flag, which allows us to ignore
     * all Java security checks.
     * @param f The private field to access
     * @param toObtainFrom The object to access the field from
     * @return The desired object, or maybe not at all if the JVM realizes
     * we're being naughty
     * @deprecated You really shouldn't be using this
     * @implNote Wow, if we're really lucky, this might even work!
     */
    public static final Object hackObjectFromField(Field f, Object toObtainFrom)
    {
        try {
            f.setAccessible(true); // welp, its worth a try
            return f.get(toObtainFrom); // this will work on < java 1.8
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                for(int off = 0; off < 100; ++off)
                {
                    if(off >= 5 && off <= 11)
                        continue; // these offsets just immediately crash the JVM
                    //System.err.printf("corrupting offset %d\n", off);
                    //System.err.flush(); // in case the JVM crashes before that message can be printed
                    int old = unsafe.getInt(f, off); // save the old memory so we can restore it
                    unsafe.putInt(f, off, 1); // corrupt the memory, we are trying to overwrite the override flag
                    if(f.canAccess(toObtainFrom)) // did we get it?
                        return f.get(toObtainFrom); // we got it! return the object!!
                    unsafe.putInt(f, off, old); // ok, that didnt work, put it back
                }
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.err.printf("failed to hack object!\n");
        return null;
    }
    
    /**
     * Retrieves the underlying <code>InputStream</code> and
     * <code>OutputStream</code> from a <code>HttpExchange</code> object.
     * <p>
     * Or, depending on the position of the moon and the stars, immediately
     * crashes the underlying JVM
     * @param t The <code>HttpExchange</code>
     * @return Assuming the JVM hasn't crashed or realized we're being naughty
     * by this point, then the underlying <code>InputStream</code> and
     * <code>OutputStream</code> wrapped in an <code>IOStream</code> object
     * @deprecated You really shouldn't be using this
     * @implNote Wow, if we're really lucky, this might even work!
     */
    public static IOStream hackRawStreamsFromExchange(HttpExchange t)
    {
        try {
            Field exchangeImplField = t.getClass().getDeclaredField("impl"); // illegal access? its not illegal if im only borrowing ;)
            Object exchangeImpl = hackObjectFromField(exchangeImplField, t);
            // steal the ros and ris fields from sun.net.exchangeimpl
            OutputStream ros = (OutputStream)hackObjectFromField(exchangeImpl.getClass().getDeclaredField("ros"), exchangeImpl);
            InputStream ris = (InputStream)hackObjectFromField(exchangeImpl.getClass().getDeclaredField("ris"), exchangeImpl);
            return new IOStream(ris, ros);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'd prefer to avoid changing API's at this point since so much code already relies on the `WebServer` class, but I have yet to find any official way to get the access I need.